# How to display rowcount in SPGridview after column filter is applied

Tags: spgridview

I am able to add label to show count in an SPGridView which takes data source (datatable), row counts and displays, but I'm having problems when column filter is applied.

Please suggest how I can get row count after applying filter

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using now and try to illustrate the issue you are having?